# Magento 2 after installing claue theme getting error while loading home page

Tags: php, magento2

I running magento2 using bitnami docker containers and I installed claue theme. After installing claue theme I am getting error while loading the landing page(home page).

Error:

```
[php7:error] [pid 524] [client 172.18.0.1:36096] PHP Fatal error: Declaration of MGS\\Mpanel\\Helper\\Swatches\\Data::getProductMediaGallery(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product $product) must be compatible with Magento\\Swatches\\Helper\\Data::getProductMediaGallery(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product $product): array in /bitnami/magento/htdocs/app/code/MGS/Mpanel/Helper/Swatches/Data.php on line 0
```

Swatches/Data.php

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product as ModelProduct;

public function getProductMediaGallery(ModelProduct $product){
    if(!in_array($product->getData('image'), [null, self::EMPTY_IMAGE_VALUE], true)){
        $baseImage = $prodcut->getData('image');
    }else{
        $productMedaiAttributes = array_filter($product->getMediaAttributeValues(), function($value){
            return $value !== self::EMPTY_IMAGE_VALUE && $values !== null;
        });
        foreach ($productMediaAttributes as $attributeCode => $value){
            if($attributeCode !== 'swatch_image'){
                $baseImage = (string)$value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(empty($baseImage)){
        return [];
    }

    $resultGallery = $this->getAllSizeImages($product, $baseImage);
    $resultGallery['gallery'] = $this->getGalleryImages($product);
    return $resultGallery;
}
```

I am new to php and magento. I am not able to find out how to solve this issue. kindly help to solve this issue. If any details is need kindly let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says you have to make your method compatible with the one you overrided by adding the return type, (in this case `: array`) at the end of your method declaration.
This line of your code : `public function getProductMediaGallery(ModelProduct $product){` will become : `public function getProductMediaGallery(ModelProduct $product): array {`

Comment: Thanks It worked but I am not getting css on the home page do you have any idea on that?

Comment: You're welcome. Can you inspect your console and your network tab in your Developper tools and tell me what you get, please?